# How to create an Super set enum using existing enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I need create an enum using the another like as follows

```
enum problems{
   eazy,
   medium,
   hard,    
}

enum moreProblems{
  eazy,
  medium,
  hard,
  frenzy
```

}

I need to moreProblems enum using the enum Problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use case: When enum B must contain all values from enum A and some additional values.

You can also create enums that extend other TypeScript enums by using const assertions like so:

```
const GameResultEnum = {
       WINNER: 'Winner',
       LOSER: 'Loser'
       } as const;  
type GameResultEnum = typeof GameResultEnum[keyof typeof GameResultEnum];

const SoccerGameResultEnum = { ...GameResultEnum, DRAW: 'Draw' } as const;
type SoccerGameResultEnum = typeof SoccerGameResultEnum[keyof typeof 
SoccerGameResultEnum];
```

Implementation:

```
let gameResult: GameResultEnum, soccerGameResult: SoccerGameResultEnum;

gameResult = GameResultEnum.WINNER; // no errors 
gameResult = SoccerGameResultEnum.WINNER; // SoccerGameResultEnum can also be used
gameResult = SoccerGameResultEnum.DRAW; // correctly throws errors
```

I found the solution [here](https://devimalplanet.com/typescript-how-to-extend-one-enum-from-another)

Comment: The resulting variable is a constant not enum right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit from enums in TypeScript, but could using unions help?

```
enum problems{
   eazy,
   medium,
   hard,    
}

enum moreProblems{
  eazy,
  medium,
  hard,
  frenzy 
}
const x: problems | moreProblems= problems.eazy;

const y: problems | moreProblems= moreProblems.frenzy ;
```

Comment: Actually I wanted enum moreProblems kind of superset