# Alternative of enum to unify set values

Tags: typescript, enums

tldr: How can I union enums whose values overlap with each other a lot?

There is this piece of code defining a set of action values. This is a simplified version.

```js
enum actionA {
  'APPROVE' = 'Approve',
  'DECLINE' = 'Decline',
  'A_SPECIFIC_ACTION' = 'Action A',
}

enum actionB {
  'APPROVE' = 'Approve',
  'DECLINE' = 'Decline',
  'B_SPECIFIC_ACTION' = 'Action B',
}
```

`APPROVE` and `DECLINE` exist in both enums, and in the real code, there are about 5 repeated values. It would be nice if typescript enum supported something like this

```js
enum commonAction {
'APPROVE' = 'Approve',
'DECLINE' = 'Decline',
}

enum actionA {
  ...commonAction
  'A_SPECIFIC_ACTION' = 'Action A',
}

enum actionB {
  ...commonAction
  'B_SPECIFIC_ACTION' = 'Action B',
}
```

But apparently it does not. I can change them all into `interface` or `type` but that way

1. It would need initialization of actual value making the code bulkier
2. I really need only one instance of the type/interface so the definition is not really reused.

There was another way, which was to convert `commonAction` to a plain object and spread it over enum but that did not seem to be encouraged a lot. I honestly did not fully get why.

I'm curious if there is a better way to handle a case like this or I should go with `interface` or `type` even with the shortcomings. Thanks :)

Comment: I would go with the plain object solution, it is native and correctly typed. I don't see any downside for it :/

Comment: maybe you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056841/how-to-create-an-super-set-enum-using-existing-enum-in-typescript, I hope it will helps, thank you

Comment: I went with `as const` alternative as suggested by @RodericusIfoKrista